# Dataframe using Pandas delimiting values using colon, commas and sorting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, delimiter

I have this DataFrame:

```
C0  C1   C2
0   jjj  3
0   aaa  2
1   bbb  7
```

What's the most pythonic way of using Pandas to get this new DataFrame?

```
C0  C1  
0   aaa:2,jjj:3  
1   bbb:7
```

Comment: What's the logic for sorting? Should it be sorted on `C1` or `C2`?

Comment: Your answer was correct ... Please make your answer available again

Comment: Yes undeleted it.

Comment: As you did, sorted on C1

Comment: Do you have any suggestion, to make a DataFrame with the solution?

Comment: @Luis use `as_index=False` in `groupby`

Comment: Yes you can use `to_frame`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could sort the dataframe using [`DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html). You can use [`Series.str.cat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html) for concatenation with sep. Then groupby and use `str.join`.

```
df = df.sort_values('C1')
df["C1"].str.cat(df["C2"].astype(str), ":").groupby(df["C0"]).agg(
    ",".join
).to_frame().reset_index()

   C0           C1
0   0  aaa:2,jjj:3
1   1        bbb:7
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar approach to that of @Ch3ster, a bit different pipeline:

```
(df.sort_values('C1')
   .assign(C1=lambda d: d['C1']+':'+d['C2'].astype(str))
   .groupby('C0', as_index=False)['C1'].apply(','.join)
 )
```

Output:

```
   C0           C1
0   0  aaa:2,jjj:3
1   1        bbb:7
```

Comment: Thanks! I usually try to make pipelines, as they don't change the original dataframe. It's not always giving the best solution though, sometimes it's just easier to split in a few imperative steps ;) (you had my vote on your solution btw, perfectly legit)